# Can you say “回去 ____" （A location？）

Tags: grammar

Quick question:  Can you 回去 a location? or can you only say 回去 by itself?

ex.

“回去 我家乡”

Comment: 1. 回去: go home, go back, e.g.: 我回去; 2. 回去...: go home for ..., go back for ..., e.g.: 我回去吃饭; 3. 回...: go back to ..., e.g.: 我回北京; 4. 回...去: go to..., go back to ..., e.g.: 我回家去, 我回家吃饭去, 我回北京去.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should say 回___去. And usually you can omit 去.

e.g:

- 回家去。/回家。
- 回火星去。 /回火星。

There're only some subtle differences in tone and emotion depending on the context.

While some would suggest that 回去___ is grammarly correct, usually it is phonetically strange.

As a native speaker, I would prefer 回家去吃饭 over 回去家吃饭. The logic (if there are any) behind this is that both 回家 and 吃饭(or anything you go home to do) can be used standalone. Connecting them with a single 去 sounds smoother than split 回家 and insert a 去 in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

As oloopy answered, you can't say 回去 a location, just use 回 a location, such as 回美国，回家，回北京

Plus, I think there're 2 use scenarios for 回去

1. 回去了

   a) it means a state that someone has left current place and already went back to where he/she stays, for example, you and your girl friend attends a party and it's midnight now, she left in advance, when a friend of yours asked where's your girl friend, you can say: 她回去了

   b) you can add 要 in the start of 回去 to express a future state. Same example, it's 1:00 AM now,  you're tired, but the party continues, so you can tell your friend that 我要回去了.(I'm gonna back to my dorm)
2. 回去

   回去 sometimes means an order/command, you're asking someone to do something. For example, you're going to work and your dog is trying to follow you, you can say to it: 回去！(go back!)

Answer (score 2):

You would probably only use "回", more specifically, "回我家乡".

Chinese usually use "回去了" without following a specific location when greeting.

Answer (score 2):

Both work gramatically. Obviously saying 回去 standalone requires context. Examples with a location: 回去香港看父母，回去办公室拿东西。The character 去 can be omitted. For example 回家吃饭 回家乡亲 is neater and more colloqial than 回去家里吃饭 回去家乡探亲。